# alternative parsing rules is not recognized by antlr4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

My antlr parser rule is not selecting alternative rules. its always considering the first option.
ex: if I am trying to use expression to select "profiletype" its selecting xxx every time.

```
profilelist :
    PROFILELIST profilecat
;
profilecat:
id | profiletype
;

profiletype :
   ( xxx | yyy | zzz )
;

xxx :
    PROFILETYPE1
;
yyy :
    PROFILETYPE2
:
zzz :
    PROFILETYPE3
;

id:
   ID
;
```

Comment: how can we reproduce this?

Comment: Probably a Lexer problem, so provide the Lexer rules.